# Can't retrieve static json file from react router routes on apache server

Tags: reactjs, json, apache, react-router

I'm in a situation where I have to locally build a React project and then upload it to a particular path on an Apache server. It all worked alright, except it took a while to figure out how to get the Apache server to respect the `react-router` routes. We eventually created a .htaccess file to add to the path where my app is being uploaded and this seemed to resolve the issue:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Fallback all other routes to index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /events/new-year/index.html [L]
```

But I've had a request to put config variables in a json file in the `/static` directory so that these can be easily changed later on by the non-JS devs. Loading the JSON data from the file works just fine when in the application root. In the response I get:

```js
{
    data: { 
        eventDates: "20 Nov - 28 Nov"
        localUrl: "http://localhost:3000"
        pageTitle: "Some title"
        serverURl: ""
        year: "2023"
    }
}
```

but when trying to load the json from any of the `react-router` routes I get a really weird output:

```js
{
    data: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/><title>Current Page Title</title><link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch"><link href="https://www.somesite.com/content/favicon-150x150.png" rel="shortcut icon"><link href="https://www.somesite.com/content....."
}
```

I cut most of the output because it's outputting ALL of the html for the index.html stored in the static folder. Why can't I get the a good response on these child routes?

I'm loading the json like so:

```js
const data = await axios("./resources/data/config.json");
```

I've tried without the `.` at the front and I've tried without `./`. I have found that I get a response of `undefined` with anything other than the `./`

**Thank you for reading, any help would be hugely appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that there was an issue with the path. Since the relative path didn't work (and returned html for some reason) I had to use only a `/` (non-relative path?). While this was returning undefined before, after looking at the network tab I realised why:

My application was sitting at `www.website.com/some-path/my-application`, so I needed to fetch static resources from `www.website.com/some-path/my-application/resources`, but instead it was looking in `www.website.com/resources`. So all I had to do was add `/some-path/my-application` to the url that I was using previously.

I hope this can one day help a lost traveller!